# Spring - When a Destination JndiObjectFactoryBean is cached, does it keep any connection open to the JMS broker?

Tags: spring, jms, jndi, solace

We configure our JMS destinations via JNDI lookup as follows:

```
@Bean
JndiObjectFactoryBean myTopic(@Value("${topic}") String topic,
                              JndiTemplate jndiTemplate) {

    JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate);
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(topic);

    return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
}
```

On initialisation of this bean, Spring confirms the object exists and caches it for use later. Does the caching of this Destination involve a persistent connection being created to our broker as well? Or is the connection only physically created when our CachingConnectionFactory is instantiated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (only and shared) connection is created when you call `createConnection()` for the 1st time on your `CachingConnectionFactory` instance and released on the call to `destroy()` or `resetConnection()` as stated per the contract (`CachingConnectionFactory` inherit from [`SingleConnectionFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/SingleConnectionFactory.html)) :

> A JMS ConnectionFactory adapter that returns the same Connection from all createConnection() calls, and ignores calls to Connection.close()